# HTML Table always at new line?

Tags: html, html-table, newline

If I create a HTML table like this:

```
text text text
    <table border='0'>
     <TR>
        Table Item
     </TR>
    </table>
```

Is this always will generate a new line?) --------------->

```
text text text
 Table Item
```

No chance to generate like this (so without new line?) --------------------->

```
tex text text  Table Item
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
table{
display:inline-block
}
```

could help you I think.
Also will this help you
[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/YXQxQ/)

Comment: so i can do this like?: 
<table border='0' style="display:inline-block"> ...?

(sorry for last one, want to edit my comment but the time was up (5min)...)

Comment: @czupe did you check the link I provided

Comment: :facepalm: No. Sorry. Now i get it... :/ Ty. I accept your answer for the continous help and link you provide! Thanks again!

Comment: @czupe you can do that way or you can place all the text in a div and set the div and table to float left as I did in the link

Answer (score 7):

Set the `table`'s `display` to `inline-block`.

Comment: And don't forget to use <TD></TD> inside <TR></TR>.

Comment: fastest answers ever:) Appreciate it.